# Filter ListView with Checkboxes

Tags: android, android-listview, filtering, android-arrayadapter

I'm working with the newest Android SDK and I want to filter my `ListView` which represents a list of different plants, with `CheckBoxes`.

In my list I have 800 Items with different attributes (e.g. color, size, edibility), and the `CheckBoxes` should filter the list in a subtractive way. Only the list items/views which match all attributes should be visible - all other rows should be invisible(the program should work like the filtering system on [www.pilzsuchmaschine.de](http://www.pilzsuchmaschine.de)).

I tried to modify the `getView()` of my custom `ArrayAdapter` but I didn't get the right idea how to do that properly. Does anyone have a solution?

My `ArrayAdapter` is pretty the same as [this one](http://stellarwavedev.com/2012/05/android-custom-arrayadapter-text-and-icon/).

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some of the code you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to modify the getView() of my custom ArrayAdapter but I didn't
>   get the right idea how to do that properly. Does anyone have a
>   solution?

You don't do the filtering in the `getView()` method. First set a `OnCheckedChangeListener` on all the filter `CheckBoxes` to monitor their status(each of those `CheckBoxes` should have a `boolean` variable to hold its status). When a filter `CheckBox` is checked/unchecked update the status variable and then filter the `ListView`. Filtering the `ListView` can be done in two ways, manually or by using the dedicated mechanism(the `Filter` class).

Manually, when the user checks a `CheckBox` you'll take all the statuses of the filter `CheckBoxes` and match them against each element of the list of plants. Which element matches all the `CheckBoxes` statuses is valid and should be added to a new list. After this is done, make the adapter point to the newly created list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I wouldn't go with this approach as you have a lot of items.

The proper way would be to make your own adapter along with its `Filter` method(in this case the adapter will hold the statuses of the filter `CheckBoxes`). When the user checks a filter `CheckBox` call a method on the adapter to update the corresponding boolean status. Also call the `getFilter()` method on the adapter and do the filtering: `((Filterable) adapter).getFilter().filter(null)`. There are a lot of tutorials there about implementing a `Filter` for an adapter.